# Isomorphism between the first the uncountable ordinal $\omega_{1}$ and real numbers

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Recently, i have studied the proof of why the set of all countable ordinals $\Gamma$ is an ordinal and why it is an uncountable. (Basically, since it contains all countable ordinals as predecessors, it cannot contain itself, by definition).

Authors immediately concluded that since this ordinal is uncountable, its cardinal is $\aleph_{1}$.

**However, i want to clearly see that, indeed $|\omega_{1}| = \aleph_{1}$, by creating some isomorphism between $\omega_{1}$ and the set of real numbers.**

And I don't even understand how to begin to proof that or is it even possible? Does continuum hypothesis has something to do with my proposition? Or simply, does my answer has answer in the term of ZFC axioms?

If my question is quite deep and goes beyond standard axioms of set theory, let me know. I'm not advanced, i was just intrigued by that question.

Comment: It is undecidable in Set Theory that the real numbers have cardinality $\aleph_1$: this is the continuum hypothesis. So you cannot create a bijection between $\omega_1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ in ZFC.

Comment: "The set of all ordinals is an ordinal". This is wrong. The collection of all ordinals is a proper class, not a set, and not an ordinal. You are missing some major hypotheses in that statement. Did you mean, "the set of all **countable** ordinals"? The conclusion that its cardinality is $\aleph_1$ is not merely because it is uncountable, but because it is the **smallest** uncountable ordinal; and $\aleph_1$ is, *by definition*, the cardinal of the smallest uncountable ordinal. You have a tangle of definitions vs. conclusions/theorems there.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So, since the hypothesis is undecidable, my question is undecidable too. So thank you very much. Regarding the second comment - yes i meant "the set of all countable ordinals". I have to carefully go over my set theory book again. Thank you very much Arturo for spending time for my question.

Comment: Please edit the post to correct the errror, then. Again, you seem to be confusing "hypothesis" with theorems/results/statements. The statement "There is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\omega_1$" is undecidable in ZFC; this is not a 'hypothesis', but a statement. You may in fact assume it as a hypothesis: it is a theorem of Goedel that if ZFC is consistent, then so is ZFC plus the assumption that such a bijection exists... but then all you have is the statement that a bijection exists, not an explicit bijection you can really get your hands on.